# Android GraphView: match static label to data

Tags: android, android-graphview

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to match the data bars to their correct label. As you can see the first pair of pink/blue bars should be Q1, then Q2, Q3, Q4, and Total.

Basically I'm looking for a way to match the static labels to the x-values in dataPoints.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just have to match the index of the static label string to the x values of the dataPoint